# Cloud Server Live Preview not working with Zalenium

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-grid, zalenium

Im trying to configure testingBot and BrowserStack on Zalenium and everything works fine except the Live Preview.

When I am in the Live Preview of Zalenium I can only see the Live Preview of the docker-selenium nodes. 
I am new with Zalenium and I don't know how to do it or if it can be done.

Here is the command that I use to run testingBot:

```
docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 -e TESTINGBOT_KEY -e TESTINGBOT_SECRET -e TESTINGBOT_URL   -v/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  -v/c/Users/javier.gallegos/temp/videos:/home/seluser/videos --privileged dosel/zalenium start --testingBotEnabled true --startTunnel true
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only see the live preview of the containers started by Zalenium, it is not possible to see the live view of the tests running in the cloud.